# Application running in Docker container returning no data on exposed port

Tags: docker, vite

I'm running a vite app inside of my docker container that should be running on localhost:8080.

My docker file is as below:

```
FROM node:12.13.1-stretch-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm update
RUN npm build

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "npm run serve"]
```

the npm commands that are relavent here are:

```
    "preview": "vite preview --port 8080",
    "serve": "npm-run-all --sequential build preview",
```

I can build the docker image and when I run the command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 image_tag
```

I get the following in the terminal

```
> bcrypt-sandbox@1.0.0 preview /app
> vite preview --port 8080

  > Local: http://localhost:8080/
  > Network: use `--host` to expose
```

but when I navigate to localhost:8080 I just get this in chrome
[image]

I feel like this has something to do with my `docker run -p 8080:8080 image_tag` specifically with the port forwarding but I've switched those around for a while and have hit a dead end.

Last note when I run the `npm run serve` command locally I can go to localhost:8080 and things run as expected.

Comment: `vite preview --port 8080` only allows `localhost` to connect. But when this is running inside a container `localhost` is only the container itself, so any request coming from the host machine is not localhost. As suggested in the output try `vite preview --port 8080 --host` to allow other hosts to connect. [docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/#envprefix)

Comment: That did it, thank you for pointing out that flag.